# Разница между датами в месяцах (1ое число уже плюс один месяц)

Tags: php, дата, datetime

Значит есть 2 даты. Нужна разница между ними в месяцах, но способы, которые я нашел не подходят. Дело в том что если есть 2 даты 2020-01-15 и 2020-02-13 , то например функция date_diff() выдает 0 потому что 30 дней нету между датами, а мне нужно что бы 1ое число следующего месяца - это плюс один месяц уже. То есть
2020-01-31 и 2020-02-1 уже разница 1 месяц.

Comment: А между 2020-01-02 и 2020-01-31?

Comment: Ну тут 0 и это норм

Comment: А между 2020-01-01 и 2020-02-01 =2? Или 1

Comment: Есть совет или это продолжаться будет?)

Comment: Ну для начала надо выяснить что для вас значит «один месяц».

Comment: Вот межу 31 августа и 3 сентября есть месяц? А между 1 и 31 августа?

Comment: В данной ситуации да

Comment: Не хотите получать ответ не задавайте вопросы.

Comment: Ну тогда примерно так (псевдокот) `date2->year * 12 + date2->month - date1->year * 12 - date1->month`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так

```
<?php

$date1 = new DateTime("2020-01-15");

$date1->modify('first day of this month');

$date2 = new DateTime("2020-02-13");

$date2->modify('last day of this month');

$diff = $date1->diff($date2);

echo "difference " . $diff->m." months";
```